# CMake custom target seems to use sh although bash was explicitely called?

Tags: bash, cmake

I am creating a custom target in CMake which needs to setup it's environment from potentially multiple bash scripts.

```
function(create_ros_target NAME DIR DEPENDENCIES)

    set(ament_deps "")
    foreach(dep ${DEPENDENCIES})
        get_target_property(dep_path dep BUILD_PATH)
        LIST(APPEND ament_deps ${BUILD_PATH}/install/local_setup.bash)
    endforeach(dep)

    add_custom_target(${NAME} 
    COMMAND bash -c "echo ${ament_deps} | xargs -r source ; ament build --symlink-install ${DIR}"
    )
    set_target_properties(${NAME} PROPERTIES BUILD_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

endfunction()
```

I explicitly call bash, yet the error message I get from this reads:

> /bin/sh:  xargs -r source : Command not found

I assume this means the used shell is sh which does not know `source` as far as I know. How can I fix this?

Comment: can you show header of script ?

Comment: Probably, there is something with escaping (Note, that doublequotes you use are "consumed" by CMake itself, so command line for `bash -c` does not see them). Try to use *VERBATIM* option with `add_custom_target`. Also, you may check how your command is actually stored in the Makefile generated by CMake.